# Xamarin.iOS App terminated error when running on device in debug mode, quits in release mod but works fine in simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

**UPDATE: the app runs fine in simulator and can be debugged.**

I was able to debug the app fine 3 days ago. When i came back to work on it I receive the error below right after deploying to iOS Device. If I run in release the app just quits immediately.

I do not know where to start with this error because its not suggestive to the problem and appeared seemingly out of nowhere. I am not sure why there's an ASP.NET error, I am developing a Xamarin.Forms cross platform mobile app.

Things I have tried:

1. Updated Windows, Visual Studio, NuGet packages, Xcode
2. Deleted bin and obj folders
3. Cleaned & Rebuild
4. Erased app from device

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what this error is about?

I am using latest Visual Studio, Xcode, and Windows 10 build 1809 as of 11 Dec 2018:

```
2018-12-11 14:56:45.424 MyApp.iOS[1352:236793] Token received: <c888863b cb362ba8 3028fa09 ea6171ce e88231e3 f1d5f6a3 071e47aa 1b2511e3>
Thread started:  #9
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
2018-12-11 14:56:46.014 MyApp.iOS[1352:236793] <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }

@media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
            <br><br>

            <b> Requested URL: </b>/push/installations/e99787d6-f94e-4ddf-888d-9b4e8e680bdd<br><br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version I
The app has been terminated.
llback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.<>c__DisplayClass285_0.<ExecuteStepImpl>b__0()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.StepInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Invoke>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase context, Action step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.<>c__DisplayClass284_0.<OnExecuteRequestStep>b__0(Action nextStepAction)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
--><!-- 
This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is configured to show verbose error messages using &lt;customErrors mode="Off"/
nformation:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3163.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/push/installations/e99787d6-f94e-4ddf-888d-9b4e8e680bdd&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCa
&gt;. Consider using &lt;customErrors mode="On"/&gt; or &lt;customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/&gt; in production environments.-->
Failed to Stop app:  An error occured on client IDB412377 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.12.3.77/stop-app
The app has been terminated.
```

Comment: Could it run in release in Android?And what is the version of your device?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I did not try Android yet. The iOS device is an iPhone 8 Plus with iOS 12.1.1 (the latest at the date of writing this). The app targets ios version 10. The home page loads and then quits with the error above. In simulator though it works fine, i can navigate pages from and back to the homepage. Also I havent modified the homepage and it worked before, the error appeared out of nowhere. I am confused and the error does not tell me anything...

Comment: Are you calling a webservice on app start?

Comment: @SebastianS. No not at all, I mean not on that page at that time where the error happens anyway. Thats why it does not make sense.

Comment: Please check the constructors of your dependency enjections